# How can server notify mobile app?

Tags: rest, mobile, notifications

I have been researching for the last few days but have not found any concrete answer for this question.

I have a mobile app that users logged in to . The app makes call to an external database using REST Api and fetches data when required e.g : Button press , loading etc...

However , i can't figure out how to make the server notify a user/mobile app when something happens.>

The only way i can think of is to make the app check the server every second which is overkill and will drain battery life along with database call.

Let's say one user messages another user , how can i make the server send a ping or something to that specific user's mobile app to inform him of a new message ?

As far as i know , REST is completely independent of the server/app and the communications goes only one way : app -> server -> return data to app

Is there any way for the server to send data to the app without any initial request ?

Or if there is a better way to do this

---

I'm using Xamarin cross-platform with a php backend (Slim)

I read a bit about push notifications , but i'm not sure if thats what im looking for .

I want to update the app while the user is still on at times - like when they get a message - instead of receiving a push notification from google , the app should simply be alerted by the server that a new message is in and reload the "thread"

Answer (score 0):

Try using a realtime database like firebase.

I think, you must create a consumer tolisten the database events. With this approach the database notifys your consumer from events ocurred on the server, same as message received on server side from another device.

See if oficial docs suits for your problem: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/